# Firebase queries returns too many documents in complex data model

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying to figure out how to best model data for a complex feed in Cloud Firestore without returning unnecessary documents.

Here's the challenge --

Content is created for specific topics, for example: Architecture, Bridges, Dams, Roads, etc. The topic options can expand to included as many as needed at any time. This means it is a growing and evolving list.

When the content is created it is also tagged to specific industries. For example, I may want to create a post in Architecture and I want it to be seen within the Construction, Steel, and Concrete industries.

Here is where the tricky part comes in. If I am a person interested in the Steel and Construction industries, I would like to have a feed that includes posts from both of those industries with the specific topics of Bridges and Dams. Since it's a feed the results will need to be in time order. How would I possibly create this feed?

I've considered these options:

1. Query for each individual topic selected that includes tags for Steel and Construction, then aggregate and sort the results. The problem I have with this one is that it can return too many posts, which means I'm reading documents unnecessarily. If I select 5 topics between a specific time range, That's 5 queries, which is ok. However, each can have any possible amount of results, which is problematic. I could add a limit but then I run the risk of posts being omitted from topics even though they fall within the time range.
2. Create a post *"index"* table in Cloud SQL and perform queries on it to get the post ID's then retrieve the Firestore documents as needed. Then the question is, why not just use Cloud MySql.... Well it's a scaling, cost, and maintenance issue. The whole point of firestore is not having to worry so much about DBAs, load, and scale.

I've not been able to come to any other ideas and hoping someone has dealt with such a challenge and can shed some light on the matter. Perhaps firestore is just completely the wrong solution and I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole, but it seems like a workable solution can be found.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect structure is to have separate node for posts then for each post you give it a reference parent category eg Steel and Construction. Have them also arranged with timestamps. If you think that the database will be too massive for firebase's queries. You can connect your firebase database to elasticsearch and do the search from there.
I hope it helps.